# OCR on Windows Phone 8 WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ocr

I'm new to the world of programming, and am trying to develop an app that uses OCR.
I want the app to convert a singular receipt into text (nothing too complex).

However my problem is that i'm finding a lack of information for OCR on WP8, and how to implement it.
I would have though that it's a built in function of WP and that information would be easily accessible as to how to implement it.

Anyone know where I could look, or a simple example snippet of code I could use?
Not wanting a subscription based service.

Comment: Windows phone 8 doesn't support any OCR API. you can try some external library. Takle a look - http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/windows-phone/default.htm

Comment: @SadAlAbdullah, Pls put this as answer , add  Microsoft statement backing your answer , so we could make it a end.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently released the OCR Library for Windows Runtime. Jerry Nixon has posted a video guiding you though it, and there is also an msdn article.

[Jerry Nixon's Blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/09/devradiodevradio-microsoft-ocr-library.html)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windowspreview.media.ocr.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the same OCR service that the Bing Lens uses. If you haven't tried it: open camera, change lens to bing lens and try it out

The service endpoint is http://ocrrest.bingvision.net/V1. It also gives you information about the location of the detected text with their bounding boxes

Probably some fiddler analysis will help you to send your image in a similar fashion.

I have a little snippet below which expects the image as byte array

```
    public static readonly string ocrServiceUrl = "http://ocrrest.bingvision.net/V1";            // was: "platform.bing.com/ocr/V1";
    public static readonly string ocrLanguage = "en";

    public static async Task<JsonObject> MakeOcrJSON(byte[] image)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/Recognize/{1}", ocrServiceUrl, ocrLanguage));
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            requestStream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) (await request.GetResponseAsync()))
            {
                using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var json = JsonObject.Parse(responseStream.ReadToEnd());
                    return json;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = we.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OcrResponse));
                OcrResponse ocrResponse = (OcrResponse)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
                string ErrorMessage = "Unknown Error";
                if (ocrResponse.OcrFault.HasValue)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format(
                        "HTTP status code: {0} Message: {1}",
                        ocrResponse.OcrFault.Value.HttpStatusCode,
                        ocrResponse.OcrFault.Value.Message);
                }
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```